# CMake: Set Visual Studio project properties to inherit from parent (property sheet)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, cmake, cmake-language

I'm using CMake 3.8.1 to generate Visual Studio 2015 Projects.

Adding a custom property sheet:

```
set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES VS_USER_PROPS "my_settings.props")
```

Can't find the way in CMakeLists.txt to set "Output Directory", "Intermediate Directory" and some other Visual Studio project properties in vcxproj file to desired values. Those Output/Intermediate directories set to some default value by CMake.

Ideally I'm looking to set those properties to

```
<inherit from parent or project defaults>
```

So the project will pick up values that I have in my_settings.props

In vcsproj files, if you skip the entry for a property, it will inherit the value from parent.

Is there a way to customize/set/control those values from CMakeLists.txt file?

Answer (score 0):

Some (most?) of the property fields in a Visual Studio project are controlled by values set in `CMakeLists.txt` but there isn't a command that just sets them to what you want.

There are many properties and variables that control how a target is built.  Then each type of generator outputs a project file in accordance to those items.  That's how a generator for `Visual Studio` builds the same artifacts as for `MSYS Makefiles`.  Here are a few examples (that I remember):

1. `Output Directory` - Refer to `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`
2. `Intermediate Directory` - Controlled by `CMake` cannot change
3. `Target Name` - Refer to `OUTPUT_NAME`
4. `Target Extension` - Refer to `SUFFIX`

I guess you can abuse some of these items by making them be equal to a Visual Studio variable or something but that isn't something I've ever run across.